# Geometric mean proof

Tags: geometry, proof-writing

Given: $\vartriangle ABC, CD$ is parallel to $EF, DE$ is parallel to $BC$.

Prove: $AD$ is the geometric mean of $AF$ and $AB$

[image: Proof_diagram]

What I got so far:

$AD•AD=AF•AB \Rightarrow AB/AD=AD/AF$.

Given just the parallel lengths, how can I prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** $\Delta ABC \sim \Delta ADE$ and $\Delta ADC \sim \Delta AFE$. Can you take it from here?

**EDIT:** Since $\Delta ABC \sim \Delta ADE$, $\dfrac{AD}{AB}=\dfrac{AE}{AC}$, and since $\Delta ADC \sim \Delta AFE$,$\dfrac{AF}{AD}=\dfrac{AE}{AC}$

Comment: Sorry, still don't get it.

Comment: Wouldn't AD/AB = AE/AC?